# Authentication required to access API bearer token with Power Query

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery

I'm posting here because i can't find any solution to my problem, even after searching and testing for hours.

My aim is to extract data directly in Power Bi from the API connector.

**Which API I am using:**

I'm using the API from Exact, a web plateform for accounting data. You can find the related documents on the API here: https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-dev-getstrtd

**What I want to achieve:**

In order to use my API, i need to create a bearer token. In order to create it, I have to authenticate myself through two web page: the first one with my ID, the second one with my password. After that the url give me the bearer token that i can use in order to extract my data into Power BI.

**What I manually do:**

First I enter this url in my browser:
[https://start.exactonline.fr/api/oauth2/auth?client_id=[ID]&redirect_uri=[URI]&grant_type=authorizat..](https://start.exactonline.fr/api/oauth2/auth?client_id=%5BID%5D&redirect_uri=%5BURI%5D&grant_type=authorizat..).

It opens this web page with a text input box for my username ("Nom d'utilisateur") and a next ("Suivant") button :
[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEi3Y.png)

After entering my username and pressing the next button this next page is opening:
[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDyd.png)

I then enter my password and generate this url:
https://[URI]#token_type=bearer&access_token=[Token]&expires_in=600

**What is my problem:**

My problem is about the authentication process, I can't find a way to enter my ID and password with Power Query and get the bearer token in the generated url to used it as variable in my Power Query. As a result I'm here asking for help.

I already found solutions for similar problems however these solutions work only with simpler authentication protocol.

Comment: Does this help? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Open-ID-and-OAuth-2-0-Rest-API/m-p/693162

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. I also went for a python based solution (similar to the code you shared) and it kinda works. I can successfully enter my ID and my password, however my account is protected with a 2FA.
I have tried to export the secret code from the Google Authenticator chrome extension but without any result for now.

Comment: Ah. Well that's sort of the point of 2FA isn't it   Best of luck